# powershell ACL Replicating Directory Changes permission

Tags: powershell, acl

Purpose: get a list of users having Replicating Directory Changes permission in AD

I've been trying this powershell command and I get the following output:

```
Get-ObjectACL -DistinguishedName "dc=hendel,dc=local" -Domain hendel.local -ResolveGUIDs | 
? {($_.ObjectType -match 'replication-get') -or 
   ($_.ActiveDirectoryRights -match 'GenericAll')}                                                                                                                                                                           
    
    AceType               : AccessAllowed
    ObjectDN              : DC=hendel,DC=local
    ActiveDirectoryRights : GenericAll
    OpaqueLength          : 0
    ObjectSID             : S-1-5-21-2327505349-568064809-1496836491
    InheritanceFlags      : ContainerInherit
    BinaryLength          : 36
    IsInherited           : False
    IsCallback            : False
    PropagationFlags      : None
    SecurityIdentifier    : S-1-5-21-2327505349-568064809-1496836491-519
    AccessMask            : 983551
    AuditFlags            : None
    AceFlags              : ContainerInherit
    AceQualifier          : AccessAllowed
    
    AceType               : AccessAllowed
    ObjectDN              : DC=hendel,DC=local
    ActiveDirectoryRights : GenericAll
    OpaqueLength          : 0
    ObjectSID             : S-1-5-21-2327505349-568064809-1496836491
    InheritanceFlags      : None
    BinaryLength          : 20
    IsInherited           : False
    IsCallback            : False
    PropagationFlags      : None
    SecurityIdentifier    : S-1-5-18
    AccessMask            : 983551
    AuditFlags            : None
    AceFlags              : None
    AceQualifier          : AccessAllowed
```

Well actually what I get is the ObjectSID ...but what about showing its related samaccountname as well?

Also, are there any better ways to get the same results?

thanks

Comment: What type of object are you expecting it to be?

Comment: thanks for your reply..like the one available here...http://iotsecuritynews.com/active-directory-dcsync/ or at least getting the samaccountname instead of SID

Answer (score 2):

Since the SID can represent either a user, a group or a computer, I think I would use `Get-ADObject` for this.

```
Get-ObjectACL -DistinguishedName "dc=hendel,dc=local" -Domain hendel.local -ResolveGUIDs | 
    Where-Object {($_.ObjectType -match 'replication-get') -or 
                  ($_.ActiveDirectoryRights -match 'GenericAll')} |
    Select-Object *, @{Name = 'SamAccountName'; Expression = {(Get-ADObject -Filter "objectSid -eq '$($_.ObjectSID)'" -Properties SamAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).SamAccountName}}
```

If you also would like to see the object class and name, use a ForEach-Object loop. Something like:

```
Get-ObjectACL -DistinguishedName "dc=hendel,dc=local" -Domain hendel.local -ResolveGUIDs | 
    Where-Object {($_.ObjectType -match 'replication-get') -or 
                  ($_.ActiveDirectoryRights -match 'GenericAll')} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $adobj = Get-ADObject -Filter "objectSid -eq '$($_.ObjectSID)'" -Properties SamAccountName,DisplayName,ObjectSid -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $_ | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'SamAccountName'; Expression = {$adobj.SamAccountName}},
                              @{Name = 'DisplayName'; Expression = {$adobj.DisplayName}},
                              @{Name = 'ObjectClass'; Expression = {$adobj.ObjectClass}}
    }
```